# How to share login session across subdomains in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I've configured my app to share cookies across all subdomains like in the following

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

What drive me nuts is that despite having same cookies (as shown in browser consoles), I cant read out the same session in the back end, the subdomain part just wont set 'current_user', I checked into session['warden.user.user.key'] and the request have subdomain involved just wont show anything.

I'm using jQuery AJAX calls to get data if it has anything to do with the problem.

EDIT: I'm using devise to handle user models, and not persisting sessions to db (using cookies only)